# Calling multiple methods asynchronously in single method in ASP.NET MVC Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, asp.net-mvc-5, async-await

In an `ASP.NET MVC` application, I have two methods in my `Service.cs` as shown below (methods are simplified for brevity) and I want to call these methods asynchronously using `async`. But after calling the first method (Save) from the `Controller` I want too return the result of this action without waiting the second method (SendEmail). But in this case I have to return result and do not know how to manage this using `ASP.NET MVC` async. Could you pls give some suggestion for this scenario? I think I have to use `async` in all of the chain methods but not sure how to build this chain. Any help would be appreciated.

***Controller:***

```
public JsonResult AddRecord() {
var result = service.Save();
//I need to return the result after record is added (without waiting the email sent)

service.SendEmail();    
}
```

***Service:***

```
public MyEntity Save() {
    //
}


public void SendEmail() {
    //
}
```

Comment: await Task.Run(() => { service.SendEmail(); });?

Comment: Could you please post your answer by using the code above? Thanks in advance...

Comment: @nalnpir has already done this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scenarios i can think about. using an anonymous task

```
public JsonResult AddRecord() {
var result = service.Save();
//I need to return the result after record is added (without waiting the email sent)

Task.Run(() => service.SendEmail()); 
return result;
}
```

Second scenario would be to make your SendEmail method async, this way it will be almost the same as the task thing usually its say its not a good idea to use async methods but i think this particular scenario fit the criteria

Comment: you've forgot an `await` keyword before Task.Run

Comment: No i did not, he does not want to await the result of the task, moreover you cant await in a non async method or task

Comment: Yes, I was wrong, sure. This method should return a result, of course, you're right.

Comment: Thanksfor reply. Should I also make the methods async in Service as in Alexander's answer? Which one is more suitable for my situation? This or Alexander's post? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Honestly i dont see the upside of making the save method async, since you stated that you want that done before returning and what is more you dont have any other action in your method, you usually want using async patterns when you have something that takes a long time to run and you dont want to freeze your ui in the process, hence in this case you dont want to await the email, but you do need to wait for the save to be over before going further. Usually my thumb rule is dont solve a problem you dont have, and the save method is more than fine the way it is

Comment: Thanks, I tried and that is exactly what I want. There is no need to make SendEmail() methd async.

Answer (score 1):

you can try to do so:

```
public class Service
{
    public Task<MyEntity> SaveAsync()
    {
        return Task.Run(() => Save());
    }

    public MyEntity Save()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        var entity = new MyEntity();
        return entity;
    }

    public Task SendEmailAsync()
    {
        return Task.Run(() => SendEmail());
    }

    public void SendEmail()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Console.WriteLine("The message is sent");
    }
}
```

and create Controller, or other service, some this:

```
public class SomeController
{
    private readonly Service _service;

    public SomeController()
    {
        _service = new Service();
    }

    public MyEntity AddRecord()
    {
        var resultTask = _service.SaveAsync();
        _service.SendEmailAsync();

        return resultTask.Result;
    }

    public async Task<MyEntity> AddRecord2()
    {
        var resultTask = _service.SaveAsync();

        _service.SendEmailAsync();

        //var result = await resultTask;
        //return result;

        return await resultTask;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to call SendMail() from a different thread.
Try looking into [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/) that helps with Background jobs.

Comment: Thanks but for this scenario I do not want to use Hangfire that I have already used for particular other scenarios...

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to change the behavior of `SendEmail` and its name so that it doesn't actually send an email. It adds a request to send an email to a queue. Your method call might look like:

```
service.QueueEmail(someData);
```

There's no need for this to be asynchronous (and no benefit) because all you're doing is adding something to a queue. A separate process reads from the queue and sends emails.

That will lead to keeping your service more focused. The more detailed code that knows how to send an email will live somewhere else. That code can then handle that complexity more effectively. For example it can incorporate retry logic. And as you have other processes in your application that send emails they can re-use that process.

Comment: Could you please include my codes above in your answer as Alexander did? On the other hand, what about using Task.Run() for this scanario as Alexandr's answer? Thanks a lot.

Comment: My solution doesn't quite lend itself to that. In fact it's hardly even a "solution." It's more of a suggestion to design your email solution separately. If `service` sends an email the solution will be sub-optimal. If you use `Task.Run()` then what happens if sending the email throws an exception? It just won't get sent. That's why I'd start with something that lets you add requests to send emails to a queue. One you have that, this class is done. Then separately you solve the problem of how to send the email requests that are on the queue. But I wouldn't try to solve both at once.

Comment: Thanks for reply. That is exactly where I am very confused because I need to return response just after Adding new record. On the other hand, of course thought that what about there is a problem while sending email. But in this case the user would already close the form if there is no error regarding to adding record and I can only monitor the email statuses on a different page by writing the exception to the database in case this situation. So, is there a better approach in this situation? Thanks in advance...

Comment: I've usually had a separate process to send emails, like a service that I send the request to. Having sent that request, my process can continue and assume that the email is sent. (There's not much else it could do.) That process is usually not part of the web application. It's something that just continually monitors its own queue and sends emails. That also minimizes the number of places where SMTP configuration is stored. Regardless of how you solve the email problem, this moves it out of a class which can't effectively handle sending emails.